# RestKit 0.20 Error Domain=org.restkit.RestKit.ErrorDomain Code=-1016

Tags: ios, objective-c, restkit-0.20

I am trying to integrate RestKit 0.20 to My Project So for Example i am using google rss reader for sample project.

This is the response for Xml 
         
            
           /
            
            /category>
            
           &

This is the Xml from where i have to get the data.

RKObjectMapping* articleMapping = [RKObjectMapping mappingForClass:[News class]];
    [articleMapping addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary:@{
     @"title": @"title",
     @"link": @"link",
     @"guid": @"guid",
     @"pubDate": @"pubDate",
     @"description": @"description"
     }];

```
       NSURL* url = [[NSURL alloc]initWithString:@"http://news.google.com"];
RKObjectManager* objectManager = [RKObjectManager managerWithBaseURL:url];

NSURLRequest* request = [objectManager requestWithObject:nil method:RKRequestMethodGET path:@"/?output=rss" parameters:nil];


RKResponseDescriptor *responseDescriptor = [RKResponseDescriptor responseDescriptorWithMapping:articleMapping pathPattern:nil keyPath:@"item" statusCodes:RKStatusCodeIndexSetForClass(RKStatusCodeClassSuccessful)];

RKObjectRequestOperation *objectRequestOperation = [[RKObjectRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:request responseDescriptors:@[ responseDescriptor ]];
[objectRequestOperation setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, RKMappingResult *mappingResult) {
    RKLogInfo(@"Load collection of Articles: %@", mappingResult.array);
} failure:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
    RKLogError(@"Operation failed with error: %@", error);
}];



[objectRequestOperation start];
```

Above is the code i used to get data When i run the app i am getting the following error

I restkit.network:RKObjectRequestOperation.m:174 GET 'http://news.google.com/?output=rss'
2013-05-28 12:24:15.076 TestApp[8940:15203] E restkit.network:RKObjectRequestOperation.m:569 Object request failed: Underlying HTTP request operation failed with error: Error Domain=org.restkit.RestKit.ErrorDomain Code=-1016 "Expected content type {(
    "application/xml",
    "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
    "application/json"
)}, got application/rss+xml" UserInfo=0xa80a3d0 {NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion=NFE/1.0Top Stories - Google News

Can any one help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As the exception says, RestKit is expecting one of:

1. "application/xml"
2. "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
3. "application/json"

But it's receiving "application/rss+xml". You just need to tell RestKit what to expect.

You can ask RestKit if it already understands the mime type:

```
[RKMIMETypeSerialization registeredMIMETypes];
```

If not you'll need to register a serializer with `RKMIMETypeSerialization`.

And you can tell the object manager what mime type to expect:

```
[objectManager setAcceptHeaderWithMIMEType:@"application/rss+xml"];
```

Comment: Hi Wain thanks for the response, I can solve the error problem but i am getting below error